# Discrepancy: steady state of scaled Brownian motion on sphere is not a harmonic function

Tags: manifolds, brownian-motion, harmonic-functions, steady-state

**Brief Background**
If you are familiar with Brownian motion in the sphere via SDEs in local coordinates/heat kernel, you can easily skip to the question. Otherwise, here is a brief background, which I hope is correctly written up.

Define Brownian motion on the sphere as the Markov process with transition density $p$ solving
$$\frac{\partial p }{\partial t} = \frac12 \Delta_M p,$$
where $\Delta_M$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the sphere. Using the parameterization,
$$(\theta, \phi) \mapsto (\cos \phi \sin \theta, \sin \phi \sin \theta, \cos\theta)^T$$
and writing $\mathscr{L}=\frac12 \Delta_M$, we can write down the infinitesimal generator $\mathscr{L}$ in local coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$ as
$$\mathscr{L}f = \frac12 \cot \theta  \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} +\frac12 \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi^2} \right).$$

If a steady-state $p_\infty(\theta, \phi)=\lim_{t \to \infty}p(t,\theta, \phi)$ exists, it must then be a harmonic function, i.e.
$$\Delta_M p_\infty =0.$$

It is well known that the steady state PDF of the Langevin SDE
$$dX_t = (\operatorname{div}_M g^{-1}-g^{-1} \nabla U)dt+\sqrt{2g^{-1}}dB_t$$
is
$$p_\infty \propto  e^{-U}\sqrt{\det g}$$
where $g$ is the metric tensor of the manifold, and $U$ is some potential defined in the local coordinates. Setting $U=0$, then the steady state of
$$dX_t = (\operatorname{div}_M g^{-1})dt+\sqrt{2g^{-1}}dB_t$$
is
$$p_\infty \propto \sqrt{\det g}.$$
Now this SDE only differs from the SDE for Brownian motion on a manifold by a factor of $1/2$ in the drift and $\sqrt{2}$ in the diffusion coefficient.

**My Question**
For the sphere, we have
$$g = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \sin^2 \theta\\
\end{pmatrix},$$
so the steady state is therefore,
$$p_\infty(\theta, \phi)= \sin(\theta),$$
since $\theta \in (0,\pi)$ for the parameterization above. I have verified indeed that this makes the RHS of the Fokker Planck equation associated to the last displayed SDE vanish. However,
$$\Delta_M p_\infty \neq 0,$$
indeed we obtain
$$\Delta_M \sin \theta = \frac{\cos^2 \theta-\sin^2\theta}{\sin\theta} \neq 0.$$
*What can explain this discrepancy?* In other words, I have a derived a steady state PDF but it is not a harmonic function on the manifold, which appears to be a contradiction. Am I missing something simple, or have I made a mistake in understanding the theory?

Thanks in advance and let me know if I should include anymore details in the background or the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough "reputation" to post a comment. It is also an old question, but having it be useful to me I will still try to write the answer.
As you have said, the generator of the process is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the sphere.  Denote by $p_t(dx)$ the measure  $\mathbb P (X_t \in dx)$. Then for finding the Fokker-Planck equation you should fix some reference measure. Here it is convinient to fix $d\textrm{vol}$, and denote by $q_t$ the density $dp_t/d\textrm{vol}$. A way to recover the Fokker-Planck equation is to integrate the ito formula to obtain (formally) for every test function $f$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\mathbb E[f(X_t)] = \int_M d\textrm{vol} \,\,q_t \,\Delta_g f 
$$
Now you use the self adjointness of the Laplace-Beltrami operator
but in the Fokker-Planck equation you find the adjoint of the.
\
So, what it seems to me to be wrong in the text you wrote is the Fokker-Planck equation. If $p_t$ is a measure the you should keep the Fokker-Planck equation in the weak form (the one I wrote above) or use the formal adjoint of the Laplace-Beltrami with respect to the pairing measure-function, which is not the $L^2$ product for which the operator is self adjoint. Otherwise the F-P equation is the evolution which followed by the density $q$

Comment: +1 I think this is hitting the nail on the head but can I ask you to clarify it a little. There is a typo in the last paragraph "find the adjoint of the. \ So,". Essentially, I obtained a Fokker-Planck $p_t = \mathscr{L}^* p$ by performing the usual argument on $\int f(y)p(t,x,y) dy$ but from what I understand here, for looking at Markov processes on Riemannian manifolds, we should start with $\int_M f(y) p(t,x,y) \nu(dy)$ where $\nu(dy) =\sqrt{\det g(y)} dy$. Sorry if this seems like I am rewriting what you wrote, just trying to see if I understand correctly.